# How to apply multiple filters to image in kinrticjs?

Tags: kineticjs

I have applied multiple filters for kinetic.Image like following,

```
//Invert 
yoda.filters([Kinetic.Filters.Invert]);
layerImage.draw();
//GrayScale
yoda.filters([Kinetic.Filters.Grayscale]);
layerImage.draw();
//Brighten
yoda.filters([Kinetic.Filters.Brighten]);
yoda.brightness(slider.value);
layerImage.batchDraw();
//RGB
yoda.filters([Kinetic.Filters.RGB]);
yoda.red(250);
yoda.green(250);
yoda.blue(0);
```

When I apply one filter in original image, I got expected image after I am trying to apply another filter to image, it affects only from original image it does not retain the previous changes.
but what I expect need changes from recently applied changes in image.

- step 1: Original Image - GrayScale=Grayscale Image
- step 2: Grayscale Image - RGB= RGB Image from Original Image,
- step 3: expected image( RGB from Grayscale Image)

Comment: KineticJS does not allow more than 1 filter at a time.

Comment: Hi markE thanks for your reply, Is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: You could use a 3rd party script like CamanJS to pre-process the image: http://camanjs.com/